# quasi linear second order PDE.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve 
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} +4 u +2 \sin^2x,\quad x\in (0,\pi)$$
With the codition $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\pi,t)= u(x,0)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,0)=0.$

---

I assumed that 
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n\geq0 } u_n(t)\cos(n x),$$
Then 
$$u_n''(t)=(4-n^2)u_n(t)+b_n$$
where $b_0=-1$ and $b_2=1$ and $b_n=0$ elsewhere, I'm I right ?

Answer (score 0):

This is non-homogeneous wave equation. To solve this assume $u(x,t)=w(x,t)+v(x)$ with that the function $w$ and its partial derivatives are tends to $0$ as $t\to \infty$. Differentiate and substitute in the equation, we get

$$w_{tt}=w_{xx}+v''+4w(x,t)+4v(x)+2\sin^2x$$ 
and
$$u_x(x,t)=w_x(x,t)+v'(x)$$ 
$$u_t(x,t)=w_t(x,t)$$

the second equation implies that $u_x(0,t)=w_x(0,t)+v'(0)=0$ and $u_x(\pi,t)=w_x(\pi,t)+v'(\pi)$ as $t\to \infty$ we get that $v'(0)=0=v'(\pi)$

In the first equation, as $t\to \infty$, we have
$v''+4v+2\sin^2x=0$, solving this O.D.E

Now, by separation of variables $w(x,t)=\sum{a_n \cos(nx)}$

and the final solution is $u=w+v$.

Comment: Mathematica tells me that there is no solutiont to ODE $v''+4v+2\sin^2 x=0$ with the conditions $v'(0)=v'(\pi)=0$.

Comment: yea it should have $v(0)$, but this can be easily seen by notice that $v'(x)=u_x(x,t)$, ($w_x(x,t)\to 0$, as $t\to \infty$), so $v(x)=\int_0^x u(s,t)ds$, $0\le x\le\pi$. You can use $v(0)=0$.

Comment: Can you elaborate ?